# PAMIE: get hwnd of IE window

Tags: python, internet-explorer, winapi, automation, pamie

I'm using PAMIE, and I need the window handle of the IE window corresponding to the PAMIE instance. How would I go about getting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple trial and error:

```
self._ie.hwnd
```